# Direct 2D rectangle blur effect

Tags: direct2d

Iam new to Direct2D. I want to apply a blur effect on a rectangle. Direct2D effects are available only in windows2008 preview. Please Help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it myself by applying guassian blur to rectangle and shifting it